# Replace string based on dual conditions

Tags: r, regex, stringr

Suppose I have a data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c("m,dt,f,m","dt,t,d,e","m,t,e,x", "m,x,dt,f"))
```

And I want to search for rows that contain both "m" & "dt" in the string. That is, both "m" & "dt" need to be present. So in the data frame above rows 1 and 4 meet the condition, but not 2 or 3 - but they all contain "m" or "dt". Once I have located them, I want to replace them with another string, say "John".

So, df[1,1] would be equal to "John,f,m" or even "John" (that would be better).

I have been using the stringr package but cant seem to figure out how to get the condition "m" & "dt" to hold. FYI - I am doing variants of the below:

```
b <-  a$a %>% str_replace_all("dt|m","John")
```

Currently I have the "or" condition, but I need to figure out the "and" condition.

Any ideas?

Comment: `df$a[grepl("(?=.*dt)(?=.*m)", df$a, perl = TRUE)] <- "John"` (assuming it's a `character`)

Comment: Another option that is more safe `df$a[with(df, grepl("dt", a) & grepl("m", a))] <- "John"`  If i is a `factor` `levels(df$a)[grepl("dt", levels(df$a)) & grepl("dt", levels(df$a))] <- "John"`

Answer (score 1):

A complete example using lookaheads:

```
library("stringr")
df <- data.frame(a=c("m,dt,f,m","dt,t,d,e","m,t,e,x", "m,x,dt,f"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df$a[str_detect(df$a, "(?=.*\\bm\\b)(?=.*\\bdt\\b)")] = "John"
df
```

This uses two pos. lookaheads with `m` and `dt` and "boundaries" on each site, respectively.

```
(?=.*\bm\b)   # looking for m with "boundaries
(?=.*\bdt\b)  # looking for dt with "boundaries"
```

Comment: That is fantastic! Don't suppose you can explain, or direct me to some text that explains, the boundaries part?

Comment: Of course: http://stringr.tidyverse.org/articles/regular-expressions.html#matching-multiple-characters